# How to increase the microphone gain while recording?

Tags: android, videochat

I'm building video chat application. During the call only one side audio is clear and other side its feeble and quiet. I want to increase the gain of microphone on the device so that the voice is clearly audible at other side.
Can any one tell me how to increase the Microphone gain programatically in android?

More specifically which API should I use for this?

Answer (score -1):

When the microphone is open, it used the volume of the AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC.

Try to increase this volume and check if the microphone volume also increased.